# Forçar usuario a digitar numeros inteiros em uma matriz

Tags: c, while

Pessoa, qual seria a melhor estrutura para forçar o usuário a digitar números inteiros positivos dentro de um vetor (array), o fragmento de código que copiei aqui está dentro de uma função, ela funciona ok quando executada pela primeira vez, porem se eu a chamo de novo em um outro momento, o sistema não considera o valor digitado, e sim o  da posição de i. por exemplo

```
int consumidor[50];
int i = 0, continuar = 1;

while (continuar = 1){

while (consumidor[i] < 1) 

{

printf("Insira o código do consumidor a ser cadastrado: ");

scanf_s("%d", &consumidor[i]);

if (consumidor[i] < 1) {

printf("Digite um código superior a '0'.\n");
            }


i++;

printf("Deseja inserir um novo consumidor? Digite '1' para sim ou tecle qualquer outra tecla para sair. ");



scanf_s("%d", &continuar);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apesar de você dizer que está correto você notou que aqui: `while (continuar = 1){` você está atribuindo 1 à variável `continuar` e não verificando se seu valor é 1?

```
int consumidor[50];
int i = 0, continuar = 1;
while (continuar == 1 && i < 50) {
    do {
        printf("Insira o código do consumidor a ser cadastrado: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &consumidor[i]);
        if (consumidor[i] < 1) {
            printf("O código precisa ser superior a '0'.\n");
        }
    } while (consumidor[i] < 1);
    i++;
    printf("Deseja inserir um novo consumidor? Digite '1' para sim ou '2' para sair. ");
    scanf_s("%d", &continuar);
}
```